# Make a grid and its items resize to fit the container

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build a grid that fits into a set size container. This means that if I change the number of grid items (which can be done via a prompt) then the items will get smaller or larger depending on the number of grid items.

Currently, the grid overflows outside the container. Instead, I need the grid items to resize to always fill the same size container, no matter the number of grid items.

I've built the grid in JS, which I know is a bit low-performance and not recommended, but this is per a set brief from an online task.

I've tried a few things, including using `auto-fit` and `auto-fill` on the `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`, but neither are working. Instead, they seem to break the grid layout entirely into one single column.

I've added a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9nLk4prj/

p.s. sorry if this is unclear - this is my first StackOverflow question.

Comment: remove : `align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;` and children won't shrink anymore to fit in the middle of the cell.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I want to make the grid-items shrink to the cell, which they aren't currently doing. To be more specific, they aren't shrinking to fit the container, which is the behaviour I'm looking for.

Comment: Solved it by adding in clear sizing and switched from trying to use vh and vw.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b07ueygz/ it respects the grid-gap of 1em without shrinking down to their padding value

Comment: ?? where is the vh/vw sizing in the snippet you provided at first ??